# Windows 8 Javascript insanity - variable undefined

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I'm working through some Windows 8 tutorials from the msdn website. Specifically I'm on [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974582.aspx).

Part of my code (copied from the tutorial is blowing my mind why it's erroring. Sample below:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var list = getBlogPosts();
    var groupedItems = list.createGrouped(
        function groupKeySelector(item) { return item.group.key; },
        function groupDataSelector(item) { return item.group; }
    );
    var dataPromises = [];
    var blogs;
    var blogPosts = new WinJS.Binding.List();

    function getFeeds() {
        blogs = [
            {
                key: "blog1",
                url: 'http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/atom.aspx',
                title: 'tbd', updated: 'tbd',
                acquireSyndication: acquireSyndication, dataPromise: null
            },
            // lots more entries ...
        ];

        blogs.forEach(function (feed) {
            feed.dataPromise = feed.acquireSyndication(feed.url);
            dataPromises.push(feed.dataPromise);
        });

        return WinJS.Promise.join(dataPromises).then(function () { return blogs });
    }

// more code...

})();
```

At the line `dataPromises.push(feed.dataPromise);` I get the error `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference`. You can see `dataPromises` is defined and initialised to an empty array near the top of the file (I've also tried initialising it with `new Array();`).

What am I doing wrong here??? I'm guessing I've made some stupid screw up...  Incidentally, the 3 places `dataPromises` appears in the snippet above are the **only** places it appears anywhere in the project.

My first thought was hoisting but unless something magical is going on, I'm not explicitly declaring `dataPromises` in any local scopes that might be overriding the top function scope.

Comment: @nalply he's using Internet Explorer **10**.

Comment: where is `acquireSyndication` defined?

Comment: have you tried changing the name of your variable? perhaps `dataPromises` is being overwritten elsewhere?

Comment: @epascarello it's the next function in the file.

Comment: @jbabey Just tried changing it to `blogDataPromises` same error same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not following the tutorial correctly. The line

```
var list = getBlogPosts();
```

replaces the `new WinJS.Binding.List()` call, which occurs after the line that initializes `dataPromises`.

The problem is that `getBlogPosts()` is calling `getFeeds()`, and `getFeeds` is trying to push results onto `dataPromises` but the line `var dataPromises = []` hasn't executed yet, so `dataPromises` is still `undefined`.

Move the call to `getBlogPosts()` to after the initialization of the `dataPromises` variable.

Stepping through the code in the debugger line by line should have exposed this problem in a fairly straightforward manner.

Comment: AH! Knew it was something stupid. Looks like I'm just having on of those days.  Thank you!